# Windows Environment variable passing through OpenSSH

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, openssh

I am using OpenSSH for Windows in order to be able to connect a Linux machine to a Windows machine.
To do that I have installed a SSH server for Windows v5.6p1-2.
I also have declared the allowed users.

From my Linux machine, I connect to the Windows machine with "ssh user@machine" command.

My problem is that once connected, I get only some Windows environment variables but not all system and user defined variables.
Is it possible to get all the Windows environment variables ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

"This is to limit security holes."

Check this out it has a few solutions.

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2006-11/msg00394.html

Comment: what I understand is that I cannot get the environnement variables of my Windows account. The only way to do it is to declare manually the variables I need which is not why I need.

Comment: Based on the linked message, you can do what you want using a script if you know how to extract the variables from the registry (or maybe someone has already done something similar).

Comment: Thats what the script would be for - To get all of them.

Comment: I cannot do that because I do not know how many variables and also which variables are used on the Windows account for my need. In fact I want to launch a software that need environment variables which name and number change frequently. So I cannot search for some of them inside the registry using a script

Comment: When a user logs in you would run the script, then when something changes the variable with the shell it will change the local variables. If you want to set them to the back script on logout (I've never used a script on logout...)

Comment: This is too "manual". There can be so much different environment specificities that I cannot do such operations

Comment: Well you would have to make the script to run through the list of Enviorment Variables - thats the only manual part I see about it? Theirs no direct way (not to my knowledge) to access them without it.